# bug in JQuery required dropdown fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I made a JQuery function to check for empty required fields inside a closed custom dropdown.

If a required field is empty inside one of the dropdown and if the dropdown is currently closed I want the dropdown to open and if there are no empty values in the required fields I want the dropdown to close.

The problem is that the required fields aren't accessible if the dropdowns are closed and I tried to fix that problem with this function.

For some reason, it only checks for these input fields if the form is submitted at least once and the required fields are opened at least once.

`find(':input[required]')` doesn't give any output if the dropdown isn't opened at least once, once u open and close the dropdown the function works.

This is the function:

```
function dropdown_required() {
    var required = 0;
    $('#visible_fields').find(':input[required]').each(function () {
        if (!this.value) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
                $('.form_' + i).find(':input[required]').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('required', false);
                });
            }
            required++;
        }
    });

    if (required == 0) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            var empty = 0;
            $('.form_' + i).find(':input[required]').each(function ()
             {
                if(!this.value) {
                    empty++;
                }
            });

            if (empty !== 0) {
                if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_2")) {
                    $(".arrow_" + i).addClass("rotate_1").removeClass("rotate_2");
                    $(".form_" + i).fadeToggle();
                }

            } else if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_1")) {
                $(".arrow_" + i).addClass("rotate_2").removeClass("rotate_1");
                $(".form_" + i).fadeToggle();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the dropdown:

```
<div id="visible_fields">
//all visible input fields outside of the dropdowns
</div>
<label class="toggle_1">Controles<span class="arrow_1 glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"
                                                       aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
                <div class="form_1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bkr">BKR</label>
                                <select name="bkr" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected hidden></option>

<option value="10">BKR toetsing open</option>

<option value="11">BKR toetsing accoord</option>

<option value="12">Vrijgesteld van BKR toetsing</option>

</select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bkr_bestand">BKR bestand</label>
                                <input type="file" name="bkr_bestand" id="bkr_bestand"
                                       data-default-file=""
                                       class="form-control dropify">
                                <input type="hidden" name="verwijder_foto" class="verwijder_foto" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" id="input_iframe" name="input_iframe" value="">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="dropdown_required()"
                            class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please minify your code to a minimal example that you faced and trying to fix. Let it be a single custom dropdown with correct lib links (not 127.0.0.1) if they are necessary to show the issue.