# Bug in JQuery function for checking for required fields in custom dropdowns

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I made a JQuery function to check for empty required fields inside a closed custom dropdown.

If a required field is empty inside one of the dropdown and if the dropdown is currently closed I want the dropdown to open and if there are no empty values in the required fields I want the dropdown to close.

The problem is that the required fields aren't accessible if the dropdowns are closed and I tried to fix that problem with this function.

For some reason, it only checks for these input fields if the form is submitted at least once and the required fields are opened at least once.

`find(':input[required]')` doesn't give any output if the dropdown isn't opened at least once, once u open and close the dropdown the function works.

This is the function:

```
function dropdown_required() {
    var required = 0;
    $('#visible_fields').find(':input[required]').each(function () {
        if (!this.value) {
            for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
                $('.form_' + i).find(':input[required]').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('required', false);
                });
            }
            required++;
        }
    });

    if (required == 0) {
        for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
            var empty = 0;
            $('.form_' + i).find(':input[required]').each(function ()
             {
                if(!this.value) {
                    empty++;
                }
            });

            if (empty !== 0) {
                if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_2")) {
                    $(".arrow_" + i).addClass("rotate_1").removeClass("rotate_2");
                    $(".form_" + i).fadeToggle();
                }

            } else if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_1")) {
                $(".arrow_" + i).addClass("rotate_2").removeClass("rotate_1");
                $(".form_" + i).fadeToggle();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_self"
          action="/contacten/leveranciers/iframe{{ ($leverancier == null ? '' : '/' . $leverancier->cot_id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

<div id="visible_fields">
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="organisatie">Organisatie</label>
                    <input type="text" name="organisatie" id="organisatie" blocked=",;()/" hk="a"
                           value="{{ ($leverancier == null ? old('organisatie') : $leverancier->cot_organisatie) }}"
                           class="form-control inputblocked">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" filter="a-zA-Z0-9" maxlength="6"
                           value="{{ ($leverancier == null ? old('postcode') : $leverancier->cot_postcode) }}"
                           class="form-control inputfilter filter_postcode">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
//all visible input fields outside of the dropdowns
</div>
<label class="toggle_1">Controles<span class="arrow_1 glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"
                                                       aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
                <div class="form_1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bkr">BKR</label>
                                <select name="bkr" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected hidden></option>

<option value="10">BKR toetsing open</option>

<option value="11">BKR toetsing accoord</option>

<option value="12">Vrijgesteld van BKR toetsing</option>

</select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="bkr_bestand">BKR bestand</label>
                                <input type="file" name="bkr_bestand" id="bkr_bestand"
                                       data-default-file=""
                                       class="form-control dropify">
                                <input type="hidden" name="verwijder_foto" class="verwijder_foto" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" id="input_iframe" name="input_iframe" value="">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="dropdown_required()"
                            class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714586/bug-in-jquery-required-dropdown-fields

Comment: How does `$('#visible_fields').find(':input[required]')` work if the `div` is empty? Also the `form` tag is missing. This seems incomplete

Comment: I changed the question, this is made in laravel and its inside of an iframe, i dont think that any more code is needed

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Is there any initialization code ? Could it be that your `arrow_` don't have a `rotate` class until clicked and hence not matching either the `if` or `else if`?

Comment: The rotate classes only flip the arrow 90deg with a small transition, there are no conditions. The problem seems like the hidden fields dont load in if i don't open the dropdown fields but if I inspect the page the fields are visible. I even tried opening and closing the dropdowns in the code so it would load in but this didn't work.

Comment: `if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_2")) {} else if ($(".arrow_" + i).hasClass("rotate_1"))` looks like a condition to me. Your sample html has neither of those.

Comment: `<label class="toggle_1">Controles<span class="arrow_1 glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"
                                                       aria-hidden="true"></span></label> ` Every dropdown has a toggle_(number of dropdown) and an arrow_(number of dropdown) rotate_1 is for the closed dropdown and rotate_2 for the opened dropdown. So if the arrow has the rotate_2 class it means the dropdown is currently open, if the arrow has class rotate_1 it means the dropdown is currently closed. so if there is a required field thats empty the dropdown has to open, and if it has none the dropdown closes.

Comment: You're right that fixed the problem with finding the fields, the only problem now is that the form is trying to submit before checking for the invisible fields. if the form is submitted once the function works. Thanks for helping me with this problem.

Comment: The required fields are still false if I didn't fully submit the form yet, I will be able to fix the problem now, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your function checks if your `arrow` element has the class `rotate_2`. The code you pasted has neither `rotate_1` or `rotate_2` and no `else` block, so the toggle never executes.

Problem demonstration:

```js
// This group has empty mandatory elements
var empty = 1;

$('#validate').click(function() {

  if (empty !== 0) {

    console.log("I have empty elements!");

    // From your comments, this might be backwards
    if ($(".arrow_1").hasClass("rotate_2")) {

      console.log("I'm going to show them");

      $(".arrow_1").addClass("rotate_1").removeClass("rotate_2");
      $(".form_1").fadeToggle();
    }
    // This is missing in the code
    else {
      console.log("I wasn't invited to the party");
    }
    // -------
  } else if ($(".arrow_1").hasClass("rotate_1")) {

    console.log("I'm out, I don't have empty elements...");

    $(".arrow_1").addClass("rotate_2").removeClass("rotate_1");
    $(".form_1").fadeToggle();
  }
});

$('#simulate').click(function() {
  // Simulates manually opening and closing
  // In short, add rotate_2 class as if it's been toggled
  $('.arrow_1').addClass('rotate_2');
  console.log("Toggled manually");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="toggle_1">Controles<span class="arrow_1 glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"
aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
<div class="form_1">
  <div>Some form elements</div>
</div>

<button id="validate">Validate</button>

<button id="simulate">Simulate</button>
```